# Как удалить определенные символы из строки?

Tags: java

есть строка, в ней любые символы, и если в строке есть символы "sdaw" нужно их удалить, как я могу это сделать? Например (Строка-"srrw" Результат-"rr")

Comment: Воспользуйтесь регулярными выражениями пишется в две строчки код, либо через цикл пройдитесь по символам и удалите.

Comment: я не знаю как это сделать, можете написать код?

Comment: Писать код за кого то, это не педагогично, предлагаю вам выложить что у вас получится, а мы поправим. Направление я вам указал, дальше хотя бы загуглить можете, примеров куча на данную тему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Gigors**, удалять символы из строк типа String, удобно с помощью метода **replace()**.

Например, если вы выполните такую инструкцию: **System.out.println("бололойка".replace("о","а"));**, то все буквы "о" в слове заменятся на буквы "а" и в консоль будет выведено слово "**балалайка**".

Чтобы удалить буквы из строки, можно просто выполнить замену нужной буквы на "" (пустую строку).
Например: **System.out.println("рододендрон".replace("д",""));** удалит все буквы "д" и выведет в консоль "**рооенрон**".

Этой информации вам уже вполне должно хватить, чтобы самостоятельно выполнить вашу задачу. Удачи вам!

Answer (score 2):

Konstantin_SH, ну раз уж все равно задача решена, то можно сделать еще проще :)

```
String str = "srrw";
str = str.replaceAll("[sdaw]","");
```

Comment: блин, я скобки не поставил [ ] поэтому у меня не убиралисбь эти буквы, спасибо вам)

Comment: Не за что) Рада, что смогла помочь)

Answer (score 0):

Можно поиграть со `split ()`.

метод возвращает массив строк. В вашем случае будет немного громоздко.

```
 String str = "srrw";
 String tmp ="";
 String [] arr = new String [str.length()];
 for (int i =0; i < arr.size();i++){ 
 arr = str.split("s");
 tmp = tmp.concat(arr[i]);
 };

 for (int j = 0; j< tmp.lenght();j++){
 arr [j] = tmp.split("d");
 tmp = tmp.concat(arr[j]);
 };

 // ну и т. д.
```

Но можно сделать проще

```
 String str = "srrw";
 str.replaceAll("s","");
 str.replaceAll("d","");
 str.replaceAll("a","");
 str.replaceAll("w","");
```

Comment: спасибо, я делал реплейсом,но я поставил сразу неслколько букв, поэтому у меня не заменеялось, было так "str.replaceAll("swfa","")"

Comment: Если бы у Вас была строка "rsfwar", то осталась бы строка "rr"

Comment: @Konstantin_SH, не существует метода lenght(). Есть метод length(). У массивов нет метода size(). Есть статическое поле length. Метод split() не принимает аргумент типа char. Только регулярное выражение типа String. `split('s')` - не будет компилироваться. Метод split() возвращает массив строк, а не отдельную строку, поэтому `arr [i] = str.split("s");` не будет компилироваться. Зачем вы даете ответы с кучей ошибок?