# Нужно после символа убрать остальные знаки

Tags: java

есть вводимое число ll+lll; нужно чтобы после + все числа удалены были, как это сделать, числа могут быть не только ll+lll, могуть быть l+ll,lv+vl и тп. Суть в том, что + может быть в .lenght(); на любой цифре;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gigors, здесь хорошо подойдет метод substring():

```
String str = "lv+vl";
str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("+") + 1); // если нужно убрать все после плюса, но оставить плюс
str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("+"));     // если нужно убрать все после плюса, и плюс тоже убрать
str = str.substring(str.indexOf("+"));        // если нужно убрать все до плюса
str = str.substring(str.indexOf("+") + 1);    // если нужно убрать все до плюса и плюс тоже убрать)
```

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы до + удалились символы?

Comment: я думал вынести на первое место indexof и после удалить макс занчение которое может быть,  ,тобишь цифру 4 поставить после indexof но, увы, код выглядел так `.substring(.indexOf("+"),4)`

Comment: сделал после indexOf 3, но вдруг человек введет +4, мне нужно чтобы он сам понял, сколько нужно приплюсовать, или есть другие способы?

Comment: вприниципе я додумался, как можно это сделать, но есть ли специальная такая же комманда, для того что я хочу

Comment: чтобы удалить символы до плюса: str = str.substring(str.indexOf("+"));

Comment: правое ограничение в данном случае не нужно... сабстринг возьмет от позиции указанного символа и до конца строки

Comment: Строка: "гидроэлектростанция". Это `substring(5)` выдернет из строки подстроку "электростанция"

Comment: @Gigors, я вам рекомендую порешать простые задачки на этом [сайте](https://codingbat.com/java). Подобные примеры будут потом с ходу решаться =)

Comment: Спасибо))))))))

Answer (score 1):

А сами Вы пробовали как-то это реализовать? Я же только [вчера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1029733/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8/1029782#1029782) писал Вам про один интересный метод, который возвращает массив строк.

Comment: да, у вас тоже действенный метод, хороший, но он и вправду слишком громоздкий

Comment: @Gigors для этой задачи он лучше, чем для прошлой. Вам просто надо передать туда "+", а потом удалить элемент массива с индексом 0

Comment: впринципе вы правы, и под второе что я хочу, он мне подойдет, спасибо, я поставлю ваш код)